# need help in preg_match command in php

Tags: php, regex

i want to extract only this text `loadcap.jpg?pd=9NE7&str1=str`

```
<style type="text/css">                              
  .ny_captcha p.ny_cap {
    background-image : url('loadcap.jpg?pd=9NE7&str1=str');
    background-size:100px 32px;
   }
</style>
```

and i am using this code to do this but every time it shows Array only

```
preg_match("/url\(\'(.*?)\'\)\;/i",$html,$match);
```

Comment: `print_r($match);`..what does it show?

Comment: It sounds like $match is failing to show any matches. Is your input text one long string? Does it have `\n` at the end of the lines? You might try adding an "s" flag to the pattern to get it to process more than just the `<style>` tag line.

Comment: sorry i am just a beginner in php..so will you please explain by editing my command

Answer (score 0):

`$match` is filled with the results of search. `$match[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern, `$match[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

[Source (preg_match documentation)](http://php.net/preg_match)

Comment: i used this preg_match("/url\(\'(.*?)\'\)\;/i",$html,$match);
$cap = $match[1];

die("<font color='red'><b>".$cap."</b></font>");
flush();